# regex, match private ipV4 starting with 10 with optional subnet

Tags: regex

Trying to match any private ipV4 address that start with `10` and optionally ends with CIDR notation omitting default gateway, such as:

10.123.123.123 `match` 
10.12.123.1 `do not match` because it ends with `.1` => default gateway
10.12.123.2 `match`
10.123.123.123/23 `match`

What i have for now is matching private ip address that start with `10` 
`'10\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'` which will allow default gateway and will not match CIDR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
\b(10\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.(?:[2-9]|\d{2,3})(?:\/\d\d)?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rZ1sB8/2)

Comment: This will match 10.110.123